# Material UI Accordion make single select from multiple select example

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm a beginner in using material-ui. I have seen an example on their documentation about their Accordion. I want to use the component but I want it to make only single select. The default from the documentation has no available props to set the accordion to only single select. Has anyone has an idea how to limit the selection into one select only ?

Here is the code from the documentation.

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Accordion from '@material-ui/core/Accordion';
import AccordionSummary from '@material-ui/core/AccordionSummary';
import AccordionDetails from '@material-ui/core/AccordionDetails';
import Checkbox from '@material-ui/core/Checkbox';
import FormControlLabel from '@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import ExpandMoreIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ExpandMore';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    width: '100%',
  },
});

export default function ActionsInAccordionSummary() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Accordion>
        <AccordionSummary
          expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
          aria-label="Expand"
          aria-controls="additional-actions1-content"
          id="additional-actions1-header"
        >
          <FormControlLabel
            aria-label="Acknowledge"
            onClick={(event) => event.stopPropagation()}
            onFocus={(event) => event.stopPropagation()}
            control={<Checkbox />}
            label="I acknowledge that I should stop the click event propagation"
          />
        </AccordionSummary>
        <AccordionDetails>
          <Typography color="textSecondary">
            The click event of the nested action will propagate up and expand the accordion unless
            you explicitly stop it.
          </Typography>
        </AccordionDetails>
      </Accordion>
      <Accordion>
        <AccordionSummary
          expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
          aria-label="Expand"
          aria-controls="additional-actions2-content"
          id="additional-actions2-header"
        >
          <FormControlLabel
            aria-label="Acknowledge"
            onClick={(event) => event.stopPropagation()}
            onFocus={(event) => event.stopPropagation()}
            control={<Checkbox />}
            label="I acknowledge that I should stop the focus event propagation"
          />
        </AccordionSummary>
        <AccordionDetails>
          <Typography color="textSecondary">
            The focus event of the nested action will propagate up and also focus the accordion
            unless you explicitly stop it.
          </Typography>
        </AccordionDetails>
      </Accordion>
      <Accordion>
        <AccordionSummary
          expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
          aria-label="Expand"
          aria-controls="additional-actions3-content"
          id="additional-actions3-header"
        >
          <FormControlLabel
            aria-label="Acknowledge"
            onClick={(event) => event.stopPropagation()}
            onFocus={(event) => event.stopPropagation()}
            control={<Checkbox />}
            label="I acknowledge that I should provide an aria-label on each action that I add"
          />
        </AccordionSummary>
        <AccordionDetails>
          <Typography color="textSecondary">
            If you forget to put an aria-label on the nested action, the label of the action will
            also be included in the label of the parent button that controls the accordion
            expansion.
          </Typography>
        </AccordionDetails>
      </Accordion>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: single select means you want to keep only one accordion expanded at a time, right?

Comment: https://mui.com/components/accordion/#controlled-accordion. they have the exact example that you are looking for

Comment: I mean the single select from checkbox. @GulamHussain

Comment: i don't think there is any prop for this because what you are trying to do has nothing to with accordion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no prop for what you are trying to do because it has nothing to do with accordion components. You can store the currently checked checkbox in `useState` and based on that you can check which checkbox should be checked.

for eg.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Accordion from '@material-ui/core/Accordion';
import AccordionSummary from '@material-ui/core/AccordionSummary';
import AccordionDetails from '@material-ui/core/AccordionDetails';
import Checkbox from '@material-ui/core/Checkbox';
import FormControlLabel from '@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import ExpandMoreIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ExpandMore';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    width: '100%',
  },
});

export default function ActionsInAccordionSummary() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [checked, setChecked] = React.useState("")
  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Accordion>
        <AccordionSummary
          expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
          aria-label="Expand"
          aria-controls="additional-actions1-content"
          id="additional-actions1-header"
        >
          <FormControlLabel
            aria-label="Acknowledge"
            onChange={(e)=>setChecked(e.target.name)}
            onClick={(event) => event.stopPropagation()}
            onFocus={(event) => event.stopPropagation()}
            control={<Checkbox name="checkbox1" checked={checked==="checkbox1"} />}
            label="I acknowledge that I should stop the click event propagation"
          />
        </AccordionSummary>
        <AccordionDetails>
          <Typography color="textSecondary">
            The click event of the nested action will propagate up and expand the accordion unless
            you explicitly stop it.
          </Typography>
        </AccordionDetails>
      </Accordion>
      <Accordion>
        <AccordionSummary
          expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
          aria-label="Expand"
          aria-controls="additional-actions2-content"
          id="additional-actions2-header"
        >
          <FormControlLabel
            onChange={(e)=>setChecked(e.target.name)}
            aria-label="Acknowledge"
            onClick={(event) => event.stopPropagation()}
            onFocus={(event) => event.stopPropagation()}
            control={<Checkbox name="checkbox2" checked={checked==="checkbox2"} />}
            label="I acknowledge that I should stop the focus event propagation"
          />
        </AccordionSummary>
        <AccordionDetails>
          <Typography color="textSecondary">
            The focus event of the nested action will propagate up and also focus the accordion
            unless you explicitly stop it.
          </Typography>
        </AccordionDetails>
      </Accordion>
      <Accordion>
        <AccordionSummary
          expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
          aria-label="Expand"
          aria-controls="additional-actions3-content"
          id="additional-actions3-header"
        >
          <FormControlLabel
            aria-label="Acknowledge"
            onChange={(e)=>setChecked(e.target.name)}
            onClick={(event) => event.stopPropagation()}
            onFocus={(event) => event.stopPropagation()}
            control={<Checkbox name="checkbox3" checked={checked==="checkbox3"} />}
            
            label="I acknowledge that I should provide an aria-label on each action that I add"
          />
        </AccordionSummary>
        <AccordionDetails>
          <Typography color="textSecondary">
            If you forget to put an aria-label on the nested action, the label of the action will
            also be included in the label of the parent button that controls the accordion
            expansion.
          </Typography>
        </AccordionDetails>
      </Accordion>
    </div>
  );
}
```